# View feed as XML in Firefox

Tags: firefox, rss

In Firefox I want to see a `<feed>` just like a regular XML. I do not want to use view-source (anyway, it does not format it). You know what they look like, but I have pasted screenshots below.

The only approach I could find is from a post almost 10 years ago, http://www.walkernews.net/2007/11/20/how-to-view-rss-feed-in-xml-format-with-firefox/, which recommends modifying `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\components\FeedConverter.js`, but no `FeedConverter.js` exists any more, neither in `Program Files` nor in `AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles`.

I need to use Firefox as I am setting up different profiles for different activities.

Is there a way to do this?

**Firefox**

[image]

**Chrome**

[image]

Comment: stumbling upon this, I am confused - it could at least display it as plain text

Comment: there is the `view-source:` prefix recommended in multiple places, but even that doesn't seem to work for me...

Answer (score 0):

I went for the plugin "RSSPreview" which is pretty slim yet has the features I was lacking in current versions of FF: "Enable feed detection" and "Display raw xml instead of preview page"

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rsspreview/
https://github.com/aureliendavid/rsspreview

Answer (score -2):

As long as Firefox does not seem to support it natively and there does not seem to be a plugin you may use this site
https://codebeautify.org/rssviewer/ Click on Load, enter RSS feed URL